# Matlab image display in specific old figures

Tags: matlab

Take an example, I have 2 a sequences of left and right images: `left01, right01, left02, right02`, etc. How can I display those on only two figures: left and right. Each loop, these 2 figures will be updated with `leftxx` and `rightxx`.

"Hold on" will only hold the current figure. Creating figures with `figure('Name', 'Left')` will not do the trick, as multiple "Left" figures will be created. Yet `imshow()` does not let me specify the figure to display based on its name.

What I want is something similar to OpenCV, which let you choose which figure (already opened) to display

```
cvNamedWindow("Left");
cvShowImage("Left", myLeftImg);
```

"Left" figure will be updated with new img without creating new figure.

Thanks a lot.
Ken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save a handle on the `axes`-object within the figure and you need to tell the `image`-function to precisely which axes you want it to draw.

Try something along the lines of:

```
figure, h_r = axes;
figure, h_l = axes;

for n=1:whatever

    image(right_bitmap, 'Parent', h_r, ...);
    image(left_bitmap, 'Parent', h_l, ...);
    drawnow;

end;
```

Update: `image` expects the handle as property `'Parent'` rather than as first parameter.