# Tell imagesc in MATLAB to use specific figure

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I am getting more than ...slightly flustered... at trying to do what should otherwise be a very, very simple task.

I want to use a particular figure, say, figure(3), for doing `imagesc`. So in the beginning of my code, I always do this:

```
f3 = figure(3); 
a3 = gca;
```

Then, I get some matrix data, of arbitrary size. Say that I got `data` of size 231 x 322. Now, I want to tell MATLAB, to perform `imagesc(data)`, but on figure(3).

How do I do that?? `imagesc` doesnt take figure or axes handles, and this is becoming very, very frustrating... thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question so that it says what you really want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab image display in specific old figures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988109/matlab-image-display-in-specific-old-figures). Use `imagesc` instead of `image`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imagesc` takes a `'parent'` parameter.  This is indirectly documented via the `image` function.

For example:

```
imdata = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
f = figure;
a1 = subplot(211);
a2 = subplot(212);
image(imdata,'parent',a1);
imagesc(imdata,'parent',a2);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!! I was about to pull my hair out!